# Clojure: exit program when Window Frame is Closed

Tags: swing, user-interface, clojure, close-application

I'd like my Clojure program to exit when a JFrame is closed.

I'm attempting to trap and handle the close event as such:

```
(def exit-action (proxy [WindowAdapter] []
               (windowClosing [event] (fn [] (System/exit 0)))
               )
)
(.addWindowListener frame exit-action)
```

This doesn't throw any obvious errors but it also doesn't appear to do what I want.

Assistance is appreciated.

Answer:

Adapting Rekin's answer did the trick:

```
(.setDefaultCloseOperation frame JFrame/EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
```

Note that that is:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation
```

not:

```
setDefaultOperationOnClose
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java it's:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

More elaborate examples can be found in official [Java Swing tutorial about Frames](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)

Comment: I'm not sure why but setDefaultCloseOperation failed with an error about not being able to find JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE (nothing about the function not being found) setDefaultCloseOperation did what was needed with no such error about not finding EXIT_ON_CLOSE. I suppose it could be different JVM versions. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's because i wrote it from memory. I'm going to edit out the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`, but the reason your first attempt didn't work is that the body of proxy should contain `(System/exit 0)`, not `(fn [] (System/exit 0))`. Rather than exiting, you were returning (and then throwing away) a function that, *when called*, would exit.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I initially thought that I needed an ad-hock function to be sure that I was passing the proxy what it needed; it slipped my mind that the exit call would be a valid function itself.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short demonstration program I showed on my [blog](http://clarkonium.net/2011/01/a-closure-in-clojure/#more-80) a while ago

```
(ns net.dneclark.JFrameAndTimerDemo
  (:import (javax.swing JLabel JButton JPanel JFrame Timer))
  (:gen-class))

(defn timer-action [label counter]
   (proxy 1 []
     (actionPerformed
      [e]
       (.setText label (str "Counter: " (swap! counter inc))))))

(defn timer-fn []
  (let [counter (atom 0)
        label (JLabel. "Counter: 0")
        timer (Timer. 1000 (timer-action label counter))
        panel (doto (JPanel.)
                (.add label))]
    (.start timer)
    (doto (JFrame. "Timer App")
      (.setContentPane panel)
      (.setDefaultCloseOperation JFrame/EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
      (.setLocation 300 300)
      (.setSize 200 200)
      (.setVisible true)))
  (println "exit timer-fn"))

(defn -main []
  (timer-fn))
```

Note the line in timer-fn[] that sets the default close operation. Just about like Java but with a little syntax fiddling.

The purpose of the blog entry was to show an example of a closure in Clojure.